# Regular expression for separated items with comma

Tags: r, regex

I have the following datasets

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), names = c( "Adam Jones, John David, Maddy Kones", 
"Adam Smith, Maddy Kones, John David", "Maddy Kones, John Peterson, Adam Smith"))
```

that is

and I wish to see the **rows that "John" is immediately after "Adam"**

So my output will be

```
id                              names
1   Adam Jones, John David, Maddy Kones
```

I do not know how to use a regular expression for that. I tried this so far

```
output <- df [grep("Adam" [^,]* "John", df$names),]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One base R approach here is to use `grepl` with an approriate pattern:

```
Adam\b[^,]*,\\s*John.*
```

This says to match `Adam` followed by a word boundary and anything up until the first comma, immediately followed by `John` as the next term.  We don't have any ugly edge cases, because if John has to follow Adam, this implies that there will always be a comma separating the two names.

**Code:**

```
df[grepl("Adam\\b[^,]*,\\s*John.*", df$names), ]
```

### Demo

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

The original solution does not give the expected answer when there is an absence of "Adam" or "John". For example, for this dataframe

```
df
#  id                                  names
#1  1    Adam Jones, John David, Maddy Kones
#2  2    Adam Smith, Maddy Kones, John David
#3  3 Maddy Kones, John Peterson, Adam Smith
#4  4                 Adam Smith, Ronak Shah
```

Using the original solution we would get output as

```
#   id                               names
#1   1 Adam Jones, John David, Maddy Kones
#NA NA                                <NA>
```

To correct the issue we add an additional check of `isTRUE` function which would ignore such `NA`'s and would give us only `TRUE` elements

```
df[sapply(strsplit(df$names, ","), function(x) 
       isTRUE(grep("John", x) - grep("Adam", x) == 1)), ]

#  id                               names
#1  1 Adam Jones, John David, Maddy Kones
```

**Original Answer**

Another option is by splitting all the `names` on `,` and using `grep` to check the position at which "John" and "Adam" occurs and select only if the difference between them is 1 (as "John" follows "Adam").

```
df[sapply(strsplit(df$names, ","), function(x) 
                      grep("John", x) - grep("Adam", x)) == 1, ]

#id                               names
#1  1 Adam Jones, John David, Maddy Kones
```